# Describe the set of all elements $x,y \in H$, such that $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The question is as follows:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Describe the set of all elements $x,y \in H$, such that $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$.

$\textbf{An idea:}$

The set of all such elements will be in a unit sphere that contains a line segment $[x,y]$ where $x,y \in H$ and $x \neq y.$

Such elements are linearly independent, because suppose they are dependent and say $y = \beta x$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$. Then we have $1 = \|ax + (1-a)\beta x \| = \|a + (1-a)\beta\|$. Then for $a = 0$ we get $|\beta|=1$ and for $a = \frac{1}{2}$ we get $|1+\beta|=2$ which implies that $\beta = 1$ and so $x=y$, which is contradiction.

Can you please let me know if I am wrong?

And if I am wrong? Can you please let me know what is the correct answer?

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean after 'An idea'. Just to clarify, are you looking for a subset of $\mathbb{H}^2$?

Comment: Hint: Just take the square of both sides and see what happens.

Comment: @Rigel Thanks! But in that case we will get the inner product. Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 3):

(Consider first a real Hilbert space $H$. The complex case follows below.)

Squaring both sides of the equality we get
$$
(1) \qquad \|x\| \, \|y\| = \langle x , y \rangle .
$$
On the other hand, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives
$$
\langle x , y \rangle \leq \|x\| \, \|y\|
$$
with equality if and only if $x=\lambda y$ or $y = \lambda x$ for some $\lambda \geq 0$.
Hence equality in (1) holds only for this kind of vectors.

If $H$ is a complex Hilbert space, the above proof needs a small modification.
Namely, reasoning as above we get that the required equality holds if and only if
$$
(2) \qquad \text{Re}\langle x , y \rangle = \|x\| \, \|y\|.
$$
Clearly, (2) holds if $x=0$ or $y=0$.
Assume now that $x, y\neq 0$, and consider the normalized vectors
$\xi := x/\|x\|$, $\eta := y / \|y\|$.
Since $\|\xi\| = \|\eta\| = 1$, equality (2) (for nonzero vectors) is
equivalent to
$$
(3) \qquad \text{Re}\langle \xi , \eta \rangle = 1.
$$
we have that
$$
\|\xi - \eta\|^2 = 2 ( 1 - \text{Re}\langle \xi , \eta \rangle)
$$
hence (3) holds if and only if $\xi = \eta$, i.e., if and only if $x$ is a positive multiple of $y$.

Comment: You get $\langle x, y\rangle = \|x\| \|y\|$ only if you assume $H$ to be a real Hilbert space. Otherwise you get $\operatorname{Re}\langle x, y\rangle = \|x\|\|y\|$. Also, the equality in CSB gives the existence of some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $x = \lambda y$ or $y = \lambda x$, not $\lambda \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have implicitly assumed that $H$ is a real Hilbert space.

Answer (score 3):

It holds for the set

$$\{(x,y) \in H^2 : x = 0 \text{ or } y = \lambda x \text{ for some } \lambda \ge 0\} = \{(x,y) \in H^2 : x = \lambda y \text{ or } y = \lambda x \text{ for some } \lambda \ge 0\}$$

Indeed, squaring both sides gives:

$$\|x+y\|^2 = (\|x\| + \|y\|)^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2\|x\|\|y\|$$

We have:

$$\|x+y\|^2 = \langle x + y, x + y \rangle = \|x\|^2 + \langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, x \rangle + \|y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}\langle x, y\rangle$$

So we conclude $\operatorname{Re}\langle x, y\rangle = \|x\|\|y\|$.

In general this holds:

$$\left|\operatorname{Re}\langle x, y\rangle\right| \le \left|\langle x, y\rangle\right| \stackrel{CSB}{\le} \|x\|\|y\| $$

so in our case we can deduce $\left|\langle x, y\rangle\right| = \|x\|\|y\|$. Equality in CSB holds if and only if $x, y$ are colinear, meaning there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $y = \lambda x$, or $x = 0$.

However, that is not sufficient. Assume $x \ne 0$.

Using the original formula for $-y$ we have:

$$\|x - y\| = \|x\| + \|-y\| = \|x\| + \|y\| = \|x + y\|$$

Squaring gives:

$$\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 - \langle x, y\rangle - \langle y, x \rangle = \|x - y\|^2 = \|x + y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + \langle x, y\rangle + \langle y, x \rangle$$

so $\langle x, y\rangle = - \langle y, x \rangle$

We have

$$\overline{\lambda}\|x\|^2 = \langle x, \lambda x\rangle = \langle x, y\rangle = - \langle y, x \rangle = \langle \lambda x, y\rangle = \lambda\|x\|^2$$

which means $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Plugging in back to the original formula yields:

$$ |1+\lambda|\|x\| = \|x + \lambda x\|= \|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\| = \|x\| + \|\lambda x\| = (1 + |\lambda| )\|x\|$$

So $|1+\lambda| = 1 + |\lambda|$.

Squaring both sides gives:

$$1 + 2\lambda + \lambda^2 = |1+\lambda|^2 = (1 + |\lambda|)^2 = 1 + 2|\lambda| + |\lambda|^2$$

so $\lambda = |\lambda|$ which implies $\lambda \ge 0$.

This is certainly necessary, and you can check that this is also the sufficient condition.